# Designing long lists in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, list

I am trying to design a dynamic list which can have entries upto 10000. Each list element is composed of a string and a integer. I have to request this list from the middleware component, populate the data obtained and trigger GUI for display. The GUI has advanced scrolling options such as drag, swipe, page up/down, line by line scroll  etc. Thus my list should be fairly quick in terms of response to requests. Now the middleware component only supports list requests upto a maximum of 24 list elements. I guess that fetching the entire list in a loop (say in a worker thread) and maintaining a backup would be a waste of resources and not so efficient. But this has the advantage that I can show any set of elements GUI requires me to show. OR
I can try to cache a certain set of elements. But then again I doubt it will be acceptable performance wise when GUI requests elements not in cache. Can anyone please give me any suggestions/useful tips on how to design such lists? What are the factors I should bear in mind? How should I strike a balance between optimum resource consumption and good performance to the end user?

Comment: I've just skimmed over this, but before we're putting time into this, let me ask: Is there a particular reason you can't use `std::list` for whatever you want to do?

Comment: Why not use an `std::vector`?

Comment: As the previous comments have mentioned, are you aware that C++ already *has* dynamic lists?

Comment: "I've just skimmed over this" - maybe reading it would be a good idea. The question isn't (just) about basic list structures, it's about caching.

Comment: Will the list change dynamically? Or can you assume that it is constant length, constant content?

Answer (score 3):

Your STL collection choices:

**`std::list`** 
Fast insertion and deletion at any point but no random access (well linear technically).

**`std::vector`**
 Fast insertion and deletion at the back only but compact in space and random access.

**`std::deque`** Fast insertion and deletion at either point. No reallocation or invalidation of existing iterators. Random access. Not stored in contiguous memory and slightly slower access than vector although the same in big-O notation (both constant time).

If you need fast random access then list is not your choice. If you need fast insertion / deletion in the middle then it is. Tricky case, usually solved by storing both types and calculating "pagination" as necessary. You understand now when you scroll down a newly loaded document why it can be so slow to paginate. This is not just a language feature, it is general feature of collections in general. STL collections only implement generic collection techniques.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is really wanting. I think the OP wants to know the best way to handle requests to the middleware in order to get the best user experience (i.e. no lag whilst data is being retrieved, quick response times).

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the middleware. You have to put data from a structure onto the screen. If the middleware is efficient, putting the data from there directly into the GUI will be just as efficient as using any std::-structures. (*Edit:* If the middleware returns pointers to it's own data, it's fast. Since it can only return 24 items at a time, it is probably not so fast.)

If the middleware is slow, and you have the resources, go the worker-thread route. If you know how many elements you are going to allocate, I would recommend using `std::vector` (set the size in the constructor). Otherwise, you probably want `std::list`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this question is really specific to C++ -- the same problems will be true in other programming environments.

Your final solution will depend on a couple of specifics:

- is it really a problem to load the entire list on start-up? Will that really take too long, or take up scarce resources?
- What are the latency and throughput for the 'fetch' operations?
- If the middleware actually retrieves values over some network connection: what should happen if the connection to the server is unexpectedly slow, or lost?
- Do you need to take into account the possibility that rows are changed or added dynamically by other users?

If loading the entire list is really a problem, you will probably want a solution where some values are cached, and new values are retrieved (in large batches whenever possible) *in a separate thread*. You want the UI to remain responsive even if a 'fetch' is slow. You would probably want to display something like 'fetching...' for rows that are still in the process of being retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

One good trick, if the GUI is requesting elements not in cache, display some dummy value (like "Loading...") for the items that are not yet loaded. Then you can set up a callback to redraw the GUI list once those items are loaded.

Doing things like this is pretty tricky with all the synchronization needed, but it is sometimes necessary if you want it to be smooth.

About how you want to store your cached data - that should be the easy part of this, I think. Definitely you shouldn't cache *all* 10,000 items - so what data structure you use is not that sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is an approach from the functional world - a class that is syntactically identical to the list, but semantically a function* that knows how to retrieve the relevant data from the actual list.

Basically, you start by writing an empty list class with an interface that has all the operations you want to do. The constructor should do one thing: store a reference, handle, pointer or whatever is needed to access the middleware data. Implement all typical functions so that they actually redirect at the middleware, and keep as little actual data as possible.

I've done similar things in F# where I had a matrix (two-dimensional array of bytes) and needed a class representing a matrix cell, and I did not want to make an array of matrix-cell objects. So instead I implemented that matrix cell class so that it stored a reference to the actual matrix and two coordinates. Accessing the data always went to the coordinates in the matrix and fetched (or wrote) that value.

And when you're done, you can always add some caching mechanism if you find you can speed things up a bit, as you hinted at by mentioning the 24 items batch operations.

*I am not talking about `operator()`, by the way. The term function is meant in a more semantic way here.